Cannot add multiple same objects to DB, only distinct are saved. .NET EntityFramework
I have a template of exercise with name, description and amount of sets. I want to create multiple objects of Exercise * amount of sets. For example I have template [{ "name" : "Legs", "sets" : 3 }, { "name" : "Arms", "sets" : 2 } in DB I want to be saved [ {legs}, {legs}, {legs}, {arms}, {arms}], but only [{legs}, {arms}] are saved.
Fragment of code
            var exercises = planTemplate.Exercises
                .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(new Exercise
                {
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Description = x.Description
                }, x.Sets))
                .ToList() ?? new List<Exercise>();

            var plan = new FitnessPlan
            {
                TemplateId = planTemplate.Id,
                Archived = false,
                User = user,
                Name = planTemplate.Name,
                Exercises = exercises,
            };

            await _context.FitnessPlans.AddAsync(plan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

In attached screen they are all saved with exerciseId 1024 or 1025 instead of all be unique in range 1024-1028. In property exercises i have 5 objects withoud IDs but entityframework after saving changes gives them same IDs for objects with same structures, altho they are diffenent objeects.
FitnessPlan class
    public class FitnessPlan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public bool Archived { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser User { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    }


I've added code not as a picture and more explanation.

When working with database, you MUST have a unique key column. Then you can can have several rows, all with its own key.

Exercises table has primaryKey Id

You don't set that key, is it auto incremented?

Just checked your screenshot, they have THE SAME id, that's why it fails.

Yes, but id ss set automatically by entityframework, if I try to add it myself it will raise an error.

Show the code for FitnessPlan.

I've added code. Here is also github with whole solution: https://github.com/NotZetka/Fitness/blob/main/API/Handlers/Plans/AddPlan/AddPlanQueryHandler.cs

"if I try to add it myself it will raise an error.". What exeption? and on what line?

The instance of entity type 'Exercise' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
On line 57: await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Problem that Enumerable.Repeat returns the same object instance for each set and your exercises collection become filled with one object. You should change it to Enumerable.Range
var exercises = planTemplate.Exercises
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, x.Sets)
        .Select(_ => new Exercise
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Description = x.Description
        })
    ).ToList();

